# Jenkins UCM plugin runs slowly

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, jenkins-plugins, clearcase-ucm

Recently, Jenkins UCM plugin runs slowly, and I think it's because it generates a change log between two baselines. I'd prefer to skip that change log creation. Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With the [Jenkins UCM plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin), you need to check what has changed "recently" to cause such a slow execution:

- size of the UCM component
- composition of the stream monitored
- number of components involved.

At then end of a job, you can check if:

- putting a tag (meaning setting up a full baseline) takes time (it can if the components have thousands of files in them)
- trimming the change log takes time.
  [image: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/58001105/trimmed-change-set.png?version=1&modificationDate=1379404509000]

  > If you are not interested in the complete change log, including all contributing activities by ClearCase, the "`Trimmed change set`" can be checked.
  >   This will provide only the latest versions of the selected UCM stream.
  >   That is for self polling, the entered stream, for child polling, the found child stream of the entered stream. For example, if the UCM stream, `latest_int`, is entered, only the latest versions of that stream is in change log.

Comment: It seems that the plugin is fired when a new baseline is created. Do you know if it's possible to change the monitoring frequency?

Comment: besides, is it always monitored and compared to predecessor baseline?

Comment: What if I want to fire the plugin on a certain time (not when a new baseline is created). Is that possible at all?
I'm trying to find new ways to control how to fire the plug-in. Thank you.

Comment: @user1762109 I guess the easiest would be to *not* select "Poll SCM", and trigger it on demand.

Comment: It seems that the UCM plugin is fired when a new baseline is created, and yet check for changes. What's the point? Is this only for saving the change log or maybe it does not fire Jenkins if the log misses something? Do you know where it's documents when the plugin fires Jenkins?

Comment: @user1762109 The only doc I know is at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that's the one and only I know.